# objects of reverse geocoding in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

When i'm using this

```
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(parseFloat(this.myLat),parseFloat( this.myLong))
  .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) =>
  { console.log('The address is ' + result.street + ' in ' + result.countryCode)
```

in a function called in constructor i'm getting-

The address is **Unnamed** Road in IN
**result.street** is not working
!

Answer (score 0):

You must update result.street to result[0].street
It will work

This

```
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(parseFloat(this.myLat),parseFloat( this.myLong))
  .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) =>
  { console.log('The address is ' + result.street + ' in ' + result.countryCode)
```

To

```
this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(parseFloat(this.myLat),parseFloat( this.myLong))
  .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) =>
  { console.log('The address is ' + result[0].street + ' in ' + result[0].countryCode)
```